# What is the correct way to install basic4android?

Tags: basic4android

Few questions on installing:

When installing basic4android, why is it recommended to use API 8 vs. Api 14 ?

If I install Api 8, and someone is running android 2.1,

- Will they not be able to run the apk?
- Would it be better just to compile a seperate version for android 2.1 by changing the jar down to Api 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any API above 7 will work fine and will run on all Android devices running Android 1.6 or above.
Some users had better experience with Android 2.2 emulator (API level 8).